# Intelligently deal with popular deleted questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, popular-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up an archive for legendary deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions)

With Stack Overflow's evolving standards, awesome, but ultimately useless questions like favorite programming t-shirt, or joke, have been deleted.  Lately though, these standards are starting to reach awesome, and also [kinda useful questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119616/why-was-the-strangest-language-feature-question-removed).

I understand why these questions don't belong on Stack Overflow and I won't argue otherwise.  My suggestion is, can we create some sort of "place" for these questions?  I know there's already the StackPrinter, but that's more or less hidden, and, frankly a bit ugly.

Can we move the t-shirt, joke, strangest language questions, etc, to, say, `Legacy.StackOVerflow.com`?  They could be displayed in some sort of read-only format, possibly hiding the voting buttons, possibly with slightly different styling—basically display them in such a way as to leave no doubt that visitors are no longer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Surely the linked question would have been a perfectly reasonable fit for http://programming.stackexchange.com? As opposed to just deleting people's work? *sigh*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I read the question and thought to myself "there was a time when people would've foolishly suggested Programmers for this". Then I read your comment

Comment: @Michael - I think that's a bit harsh.  People that don't spend a lot of time on PSE (like me) might reasonably think that question could go there.

Comment: I've been meaning to set something up  for this, but I'm swamped with work. I'll see that I get to it some time this spring.

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm never on PSE, but you're both fairly active on meta, so I would think you've both seen the wars between SO users and PSE mods. E.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl. PSE got a rep early on for "this is where popular SO questions that SO doesn't want anymore should go", and they can't seem to get rid of it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Sigh](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8tFle.jpg). Also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119725/149432).

Comment: @Pekka - you've been meaning to set up a subdomain to StackOverflow for these popular deleted questions?  Wouldn't you need Jeff's thumbs up to do that?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Adam I mean setting up an inofficial archive of deleted questions - maybe at a nice address like `overflown.org` or something. Using an actual 10k+ account, I would dump the HTML of each question (instead of fetching the mere text from the data dump) to have a historical record of what SO "looked like back then" as well

Comment: @Pekka - that's a good workaround, but I don't see why Jeff can't do this for his community.  Such a simple problem with a simple fix, ignored by all too typical stubbornness.

Comment: @Adam You know I'm often pissed off about how some things are done around here, but I can kinda see why SO won't support an off-topic archive officially - it doesn't really fit in with the sites' mission of focusing on on-topic, quality content and mercilessly removing everything else (which is a good mission IMO). It feels appropriate to have the community run a place where rejected but good SO content is kept on a more inofficial basis. If no one else beats me to it, I will take care of this.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Actually, I haven't seen those. But that's okay, I don't buy into the idea that subjective / poll questions can't be handled by tags, so I'm already at odds with SO's management. No change there. :-)

Comment: For completeness' sake - I did some thinking on this. I won't be able to do this anytime soon. I think SE should do it after all, here's a suggestion: [Building an archive of deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122249)

Comment: @Pekka - well said.  I can only hope that gets implemented.