# Strangest language feature must stay

Tags: discussion, status-completed, locked, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the “Strangest language feature” question removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119616/why-was-the-strangest-language-feature-question-removed)

(Related to [Why was the "Strangest language feature" question removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119616/why-was-the-strangest-language-feature-question-removed), but I know why.)

The question [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/3297392#3297392) was deleted, and for a reasonable reason. However, there were many important and useful tips in there despite the intent of the post.

I'd like to propose that the question be undeleted and locked (i.e. no votes and no comments with a message at the bottom saying that it's not a good type of question to ask but remains for historical reasons), like most other ones following along the same lines, so that everyone can refer to its contents without it "being a problem".

That's all :)

**EDIT**

Here's my list of potentially useful answers to this question.

- [JavaScript return gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003277/707111)
- [PHP's tricky numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995196/707111) (I didn't know about this one and would *actually have been useful to know*, ahem ahem)
- [JavaScript automatic octal conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003942/707111), see the top comment.
- [Perl modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995117/707111)
- [JavaScript methods of Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3297392/707111)
- [Checking for undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008728/707111) - I've already seen 7 new SO questions about more or less this
- [How to do that in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001994/707111)
- [Python `else` after `for`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690698/707111) - good feature to know.
- [Python's optional arguments gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2004272/707111)

and I stopped going after the first couple pages.

Comment: Might I suggest that someone interested in doing so is welcome to copy the content and post it somewhere, assuming proper attribution. I'm *halfway* tempted to create a site for these posts just as an appeasement technique. ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Good idea. 'Cause if you look closely, it has the answer to a lot of questions asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you flag the question for undeletion?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, should I do that then? Anyway, just wanted to make sure - a moderator deleted it after all.

Comment: That's how this is done, yes.  You should be aware, however, that five users voted to delete that post (including the moderator who cast the final delete vote), so... snowball's chance in hell, and all that.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, that question is mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Also, note that you do have more than 10K reputation (as do many other people on the site), so you can already see the question and all of its answers.

Comment: I believe that the answers at [Why was the "Strangest language feature" question removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119616/why-was-the-strangest-language-feature-question-removed) explain why it should stay deleted. Chiefly, that the information is useless as is because it's impossible to find. The only reason to undelete it would be to allow sub-10kers to contribute to the (ATM, hypothetical) distribution of that information to individual questions.

Comment: Erm... OK, but answers do not a duplicate question make.

Comment: @Robert: No new justification is being offered here as to why the decision should be reversed.

Comment: That's true.  @minitech: Can you offer any further compelling arguments for resurrection?  Note that the question *was* locked at one time, with a historical banner on it.  Also note that the question has a colorful flag history; there are currently 21 moderator flags on the question alone (not counting the answers), so there's bound to be some repercussions if it appears on the horizon again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not really. It's just a very valuable source of information. It explains a lot of things. I could make an archive though. (And locking it would solve all those problems.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes there is - I don't think there was any justification to undelete and lock at all in the other question, just wanting to know why the decision was made.

Comment: minitech, this post of yours says that the question should be undeleted (and even says that the deletion reason was okay), but does not explain _why_. Absent that, the answers on the other Meta post already explain why it should not be undeleted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: *"However, there were many important and useful tips in there despite the intent of the post."* and *"I'd like to propose that the question be undeleted **and locked**"*

Comment: I see the part where you propose locking, but un-deletion **has to happen first**, and you're not explaining why you think the deletion was incorrect and should be reversed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The deletion was not entirely incorrect IMO; but the question and its many answers are very valuable. A moderator can undelete it and lock it right after one another, no problem... right?

Answer (score 5):

I'm normally pretty strongly in the anti-deletionist camp, but I have to admit that I don't see the point in keeping that question around.  Unlike a lot of other locked posts that at least have some information that someone might find useful, that one is just a hodgepodge of random unrelated snippets.  I don't see how having all that information collected in one place is going to help anyone in the future, or what they'd even be searching for to find it.  In short, what problem does it solve?

Comment: Added a list of potentially useful "stuff".

Comment: @minitech A few of the answers might be useful on their own, but how is it useful to lump them all together like that?  How is anyone ever going to find this information?  If someone is having trouble with one of these language features, the language specification is a better resource.  Just noting that it's a strange feature doesn't help solve any particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

No. Locked questions make no sense: if it's good, keep it open and allow posting new answers and voting. If it's not good, [remove it from the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete), don't keep a broken window.

Locking old questions [frames garbage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112910/do-not-lock-old-questions) that should be thrown away instead.

If you feel that the strangest language feature contains useful information, feel free to copy it to your own site. I mind it being on Stack Overflow; I don't mind it being somewhere else on the Internet.